# Как ограничить количество введённых чисел через Scanner до 14 раз включительно?

Tags: java, for, while, scanner

Всем привет! Прошу о помощи. Не понимаю, каким образом я могу ограничить количество введённых чисел через Scanner до 14 раз включительно.В данном случае числа являются коэффициентами размера детали.

Вот мой код:

```
int perfect = 0;
int small = 0;
int big = 0;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите общее количество деталей: ");
int n = scanner.nextInt();

Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите коэффициенты деталей (0, -1, 1). Не больше 14 раз!");
while (scn.hasNextInt()) {
    int part = scn.nextInt();
    for (int i=1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (part == 0) {
            perfect++;
        } else if (part == -1) {
            small++;
        } else if (part == 1) {
            big++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(perfect + " " + small + " " + big);
```

Comment: ну например, заведите счётчик до цикла. в конце цикла увеличивайте его. в начале цикла проверьте, если >=14 то break

Answer (score 1):

замени цикл `while` на вот этот цикл `for`:

```
for(int c = 14; c > 0 && scn.hasNextInt(); c--) {

}
```

тут я добавил счетчик к той проверке что у тебя есть

Comment: Выдает ошибку. В каком месте нужно произвести инициализацию int part = scn.nextInt(); ? Насколько я понимаю, то внутри основного цикла.

Comment: @НагибинВлас, да, внутри цикла. на какой строчке ошибка?

Comment: 14 строка где цикл for(int c =14 ...)  - Required Type: Boolean, Provided: Int. 15 строка где int part = scn.nextInt(); - Cannot resolve symbol "part".

Comment: @НагибинВлас хах) я неправильно цикл написал)) - уже исправил